# How can I stop a specific role from talking in discord using discord.py

Tags: discord.py

So, what I want to do is stop a specific role from speaking in a channel on discord using discord.py.

Here's what I have so far.

```py
import discord
import os
from keep_alive import keep_alive

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  countingBotGuildSave = ['test']
  if any(word in message.content for word in countingBotGuildSave):
    await message.channel.set_permissions(discord.utils.get(message.guild.members, name='Foo'), send_messages=False)
    await message.channel.send('**An admin/moderator has locked this channel. Please wait for an admin to unlock this channel with `+unlock`.**')
    print(f'{message.author} locked channel {message.channel}')

keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

This doesn't cause any errors when I run the bot, but when I say `test` in discord it says: target parameter must be either Member or Role. I don't understand because I made a role named Foo.

Can you pls help?

Tysm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error itself tells you what went wrong. Your await function does not make any sense in that case. You are looking for `guild.members` with the name `Foo` but what you want is the `role`.

**Have a look at the following code:**

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  countingBotGuildSave = ['test']
  if any(word in message.content for word in countingBotGuildSave):
    await message.channel.set_permissions(discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name='Foo'), send_messages=False) # Get the role
    await message.channel.send('**An admin/moderator has locked this channel. Please wait for an admin to unlock this channel with `+unlock`.**')
    print(f'{message.author} locked channel {message.channel}')
```

Here we are looking for a `role` in the `guild` named `Foo`. You can also just use the ID to change the name to whatever you want to without editing the code (`id=RoleID`).

**The output:**

[image: Information about the channel being locked.]

[image: Permissions for the role.]